# Best way to check if an array has only holes

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I would like to know to best way to decide if an array has only holes on it, or not.

```
hasOnlyHoles([,,,,]); // true
hasOnlyHoles([,,4,,]); // false
```

```
function hasOnlyHoles(arr: any[]): boolean {
  // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `[,,,,,,].find(v => v)) || `no values``

Comment: What about `Object.values([,,,]).length === 0`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That would work, is what I have right now. But It does look quite ugly.

Comment: Why is it ugly?

Comment: Well..., I was expecting an easy way to check it without having to create a new array with the values (which happen to be none) to decide if my current array has only holes or not. But I totally agree it works fine. I will add a comment next to this line, otherwise I wont remember why I did this in a few months. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values()` returns an array representation of an object with the valid values.

As we know in JavaScript an `array` is nothing but an `object` so `Object.values()` returns an empty array for an array that contains only holes.

In the `hasOnlyHoles` function-

1. First check if the array is completely empty or not.
2. If not empty then check the length of the array after performing the `Object.values(arr)`. If the length after that is `0` that means the array containing all the holes.

```js
const hasOnlyHoles = arr =>  arr.length > 0 && Object.values(arr).length === 0;

console.log(hasOnlyHoles([,,,,])); // true
console.log(hasOnlyHoles([,,4,,])); // false
console.log(hasOnlyHoles([,,undefined,,])); // false
console.log(hasOnlyHoles([,,'',,])); // false
```

Comment: `[,,,].every` is always true? `[,,,,].every(x => 'literally anything') // true`

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use the [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check every value is `undefined`/empty like so:

```
[,,,].every((elem) => elem === undefined) // true
[,,4,,].every((elem) => elem === undefined) // false
```

Comment: `[,,,].every` is always true? `[,,,,].every(x => 'literally anything') // true`

Comment: False matches for actual `undefined` values in the array:  `[, undefined,,,]`

Comment: @VLAZ but doesn´t `undefined` means the same that nothing defined in the array?

Comment: `undefined` is a value. A missing slot in an array is completely different - it's just *not there*. If you have an object `obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: undefined}` and try do get `obj.c` you get `undefined` but the property *is there*. If you try `obj.foo` you get `undefined`  *but that property doesn't exist*. That's what empty slots are.

Comment: In an array empty elements/slots are the same as far as I can tell, as trying to get element at pos `1` from [,,,] you would get `undefined` back. In the case of an object sure if you access a property which exists but has value `undefined` but the property still exists would need to use an `'prop' in obj` check to just check it's existence. Unless I might be missing something regarding the question.

Comment: `arr[1]` might return `undefined` but that's not indicative whether or not that index exists. `1 in arr` can show a missing slot as you'd get `false`. Assuming `arr` has `length` greater than one. There are few other oddities around empty slots which make them different to just a regular old `undefined`. Easy way to showcase it is to try `[, undefined,,undefined].map(() => "hello")` would *skip over* empty slots and you'd get `[,"hello",,"hello"]`. Empty slots are not the same as slots that have `undefined` in them. Not sure why you want them to be. Question clearly asks for empty slots.